# Android AsyncTask method that I dont know how to solve

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I debugged my Program and I noticed that I wasent able to run Networking on the same Thread (I searched for this Error like 2 Days because in the Virtual Device the App worked without Problems -.- ). So now I know how I must fix it but I dont have a clue how I can give some parameteres that are not all String to the doinBackground Method.

My Method requires a url a method these i could access afaik with params[0] and params[1] in the doInBackground method. But whats with the List of NameValuePairs how can I access that in the doInBackground method?

Thank you very much for your help :)

This is my class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames;
import org.apache.http.client.params.CookiePolicy;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>{

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // Funktion um JSON aus einer URL zu holen
    // Es wird ein POST oder ein GET Request gesendet
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // HTTP Request erstellen
        try {

            // Überprüfen welche Request Methode benutzt werden soll
            if(method == "POST"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY,
                        CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }          

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Stream in ein String umwandeln
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fehler!", "Fehler mein umwandeln von Stream in String: " + e.toString());
        }

        // JSON Object parsen
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // Das JSONObject zurückgeben
        return jObj;

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you fully understand the full concept of AsyncTasks.  You use these when you want to run an operation in a background thread and this is a very nice/flexible way of accomplishing this task.  What is really nice to me is `onPostExecute()` executes on the main thread, so it can really do some powerful things once your work is completed in `doInBackground()`.  You should keep in mind though that because `onPostExecute()` does execute on the main thread, you do not want to perform any networking operations here.

**Here is a simple example of an AsyncTask:**

```
private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // before we start working
    }   

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
        //do work in the background
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        // the work is done.. now what?
    }       
}
```

`doInBackground()` is where you are going to be doing the bulk of your work, so I will try to help you out with the basic structure you want.  I just copied and pasted your code where I thought it should go so this is not 100% gauranteed, but hopefully it will help kick off what you want to do:

```
private class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // variables passed in:
    String url;
    String method;
    List<NameValuePair> params;

    // constructor
    public JSONParser(String url, String method, 
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
        this.url = url;
        this.method = method;
        this.params = params;
    }


    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            if(method == "POST"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY,
                        CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } else if(method == "GET"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fehler!", "Fehler mein umwandeln von Stream in String: " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return jObj;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject obj) {
        // Now we have your JSONObject, play around with it.
    }       
}
```

Edit:

I forgot to mention that you can also pass in `args` which is a string array.  You can just create args and pass it in when you call your AsyncTask:

```
new JSONParser(url, method, params).execute(args);
```

and you can access args in `doInBackground()`

Here is some more information on AyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html