# Can someone explain me how this code works

Tags: java, android

I got it from a page

[Android AsyncTask method that I dont know how to solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092956/android-asynctask-method-that-i-dont-know-how-to-solve)

but i am not sure how it work completly, if someone can explain me what is the while for and This part "iso-8859-1"
 i understood that the 8 is for the number of characters but i could be wrong

```
static InputStream is = null;
static String json = "";
is = httpEntity.getContent();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: the while loop is because readLine() will read line-by-line. The `iso-8859-1` is the encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code basically reads from an inputstream obtained from the httpentity, puts that into a StringBuilder and converts that into a json finally.

For understanding the api codes, javadoc is your friend.

Here is what I found in BufferredReader javadoc

> **public BufferedReader(Reader in,
>                 int sz)**
>    Creates a buffering character-input stream that uses an input buffer of the specified size.
>
> Parameters:** in - A Reader sz - Input-buffer size
>
> **Throws:** IllegalArgumentException - If sz is <=0

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

As a reader, InputStreamReader is used in your code. Here is the relevant javadoc for the InputStreamReader

> **public InputStreamReader(InputStream in,Charset cs)** Creates an
>   InputStreamReader that uses the given charset. 
>   **Parameters:** 
>   in - An
>   InputStream cs - A charset

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream), java.nio.charset.Charset)

So "iso-8859-1" is the charset specified.